# Map<String, List<String>> where value is added run time in list if key are same form a string

Tags: java, collections

I have a String,

```
String value = "Sunday  -  H15,Sunday  -  H03,Sunday  -  H13,Sunday  -  H01,Sunday  -  H05,Friday  -  H23,Saturday  -  H05,Monday  -  H16,Monday  -  H17,Monday  -  H18,Monday  -  H19,Monday  -  H20";
```

In this String we have Days(Sunday, Monday etc..) and the Alphanumneric (H15, H03 etc..) is hours.

Now my requirement is:

I want a `Map<String, List<String>>` in which Key should be Day and Value should be the list of Hours which has same day.

Eg:

```
Sunday : [H15,H03,H13,H01,H05]
Monday : [H16,H17,H18,H19,H20]
Friday : [H23]
Saturday : [H05]
```

*Approach*:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;

public class DayPartProcessingTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        String propertyValue = "Sunday  -  H15,Sunday  -  H03,Sunday  -  H13,Sunday  -  H01,Sunday  -  H05,Friday  -  H23,Saturday  -  H05,Monday  -  H16,Monday  -  H17,Monday  -  H18,Monday  -  H19,Monday  -  H20";

        Map<String, List<String>> map = new HashMap<String, List<String>>();

        String[] dayParts = propertyValue.split(",");

        for (String string : dayParts) {
            String[] array = string.split("  -  ");
            if (map.get(array[0]) == null) {
                List<String> list = new ArrayList<>();
                list.add(array[1]);
                map.put(array[0], list);
            } else {
                List<String> tempList = map.get(array[0]);
                tempList.add(array[1]);
                map.put(array[0], tempList);
            }
        }
        System.out.println(map);

    }

}
```

This is working fine and as required but is there any other possible way. I could not think any other :(

Comment: this should be in SE codereview

Comment: This approach is very fine .Why do you need other approaches ?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the OP code is working fine and has no issues but needs better ways to do it. This question is better suited for https://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Any reason to use ``map.get(array[0]) == null`` instead of `containsKey`?

Comment: @IccheGuri Nope, its not. Every time, a new list containing one string is mapped to the key.

Comment: @XtremeBaumer : I m not looking for code review, instead another approach. But will consider reviews for future questions. Thank U.

Comment: @IccheGuri : In if{}else{}, in both the block I m creating new List() which I feel its not the correct.

Answer (score 2):

Try this.

```
String propertyValue = "Sunday  -  H15,Sunday  -  H03,Sunday  -  H13,Sunday  -  H01,Sunday  -  H05,Friday  -  H23,Saturday  -  H05,Monday  -  H16,Monday  -  H17,Monday  -  H18,Monday  -  H19,Monday  -  H20";
Map<String, List<String>> map = new HashMap<String, List<String>>();
String[] dayParts = propertyValue.split(",");
for (String string : dayParts) {
    String[] array = string.split("  -  ");
    map.computeIfAbsent(array[0], k -> new ArrayList<>()).add(array[1]);
}
System.out.println(map);
```

Or

```
String propertyValue = "Sunday  -  H15,Sunday  -  H03,Sunday  -  H13,Sunday  -  H01,Sunday  -  H05,Friday  -  H23,Saturday  -  H05,Monday  -  H16,Monday  -  H17,Monday  -  H18,Monday  -  H19,Monday  -  H20";
Map<String, List<String>> map = Arrays.stream(propertyValue.split(","))
    .map(e -> e.split("  -  "))
    .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(
        a -> a[0],
        Collectors.mapping(a -> a[1], Collectors.toList())));
```

Answer (score 1):

An alternative solution would be to use a Java 8 Stream:

```
    Map<String, List<String>> collect = Arrays.stream(value.split(","))
      .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(s -> s.split("  -  ")[0],
                          Collectors.mapping(s -> s.split("  -  ")[1],  Collectors.toList())));
```

---

`Arrays.stream(value.split(","))`will create the stream for the values splitted by `,`.
The `groupingBy` Collector will group your stream by the given key (in this case the days).
The `Collectors.mapping` will transform your values for the values of the map.
The `Collectors.toList`will then collect the transformed values into a list.

Answer (score 0):

Your code can be cleaned up a bit like so

```
for (String string : dayParts) {
    String[] array = string.split("  -  ");
    List<String> list = map.get(array[0]);
    if(list == null) {
       list = new ArrayList<String>();
    }
    list.add(array[1]);
    map.put(array[0], list);
}
```

I did not use the `containsKey(..)`/`get(..)` combination here, since in potential case of concurrent access to the map, there can be a race condition.

Answer (score 0):

You could use `containsKey` instead of `map.get(array[0]) == null`. You can also reduce the number of actions when adding to the map

```
if (!map.containsKey(array[0])) {
    map.put(array[0], new ArrayList<String>());
}
map.get(array[0]).add(array[1]);
```